# i want to convert react-routing code from v5 to v6

Tags: reactjs, routes

** The code for the App.js is below (I want migrate to v6 with the Routes and element tag) **

- Help to build code in v6

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    
      <div>
        <h2>JWT Authentication using JSON fake server</h2>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Header/>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login  />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/register">
            <Register />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need in the `App` component , but you may also need to apply some changes on other components. **(check out the link below)**

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    
 

 <div>
    <h2>JWT Authentication using JSON fake server</h2>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<> <Header/> <Home /></>}/>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login  />}/>
      <Route path="/register" element={ <Register />}/>
    </Routes>
  </div>



 );
}

export default App;
```

First you must know that `Switch` and `exact` doesn't exist in v6 anymore.
Instead of `Switch` you need to import **`Routes`** in v6.

As for `exact`, in v6 the matching by default is only if the whole path is matching and not just the begining (which is the behavior in v5.) So in v6 you don't need to add exact.

If you do want that behavior that it navigates even if just the begining of the path matches, you can add `/*` at the end of the path.

**Check out this link for more information about the changes:** https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5